# Why is the middle column not showing up?

Tags: java, swing, alignment, centering, gridbaglayout

I am making a simple calculator GUI in Java to start to learn how to use Java. The following code is not working. Only the first column is appearing. Where is the second and third column going?

```
    package Start;


    import java.awt.*;
    import javax.swing.*;       

    public class CalculatorGUI {

public static void addComponentsToPane(Container pane) {

    pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

    JLabel label;
    JButton button;

    label = new JLabel("I'm a calculator");
    c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
    c.weightx = 0.0;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    pane.add(label, c);

    button = new JButton("1");
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    pane.add(button, c);

    button = new JButton("2");
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 1;
    pane.add(button, c);

    button = new JButton("3");
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 1;
    pane.add(button, c);

    button = new JButton("4");
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 2;
    pane.add(button, c);

    button = new JButton("5");
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 2;
    pane.add(button, c);

    button = new JButton("6");
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 2;
    pane.add(button, c);

    button = new JButton("7");
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 3;
    pane.add(button, c);

    button = new JButton("8");
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 3;
    pane.add(button, c);

    button = new JButton("9");
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 3;
    pane.add(button, c);


}

public static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("CalculatorGUI");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

   addComponentsToPane(frame.getContentPane());

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
  }
}
```

i tried making the label just say `c.gridwidth = 3;` but that does the same thing. When i make the width just equal 1 all the buttons appear, but the label is in only in one cell. **How do i make the label span 3 columns?** Without making the other buttons disappear.

Comment: You could try using a GridLayout with 3 columns (`new GridLayout(0,3)`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do i make the label span 3 columns without gridwidth?

```
c.gridwidth = 3;
```

You will then need to reset it to 1 before adding other components.

> so that it is centered over the '2' button

You will also need to set the text alignment of the label:

```
label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize I had to reset it.

Answer (score 0):

You're using

```
c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
```

Which Specifies that the current component is the last component in its column or row.

So comment this line out, and it should work just fine.

Reaf more About [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html).

Comment: How do i make the label span 3 columns without gridwidth?

Comment: I based my GUI off of the examples in that link, but it isn't working.

Comment: Have you commented the above line as my description above?

Comment: Yes, but then the label, "I'm a calculator" only takes up one cell. I want it to span across column 0, 1, and 2 so that it is centered over the '2' button